# Find and Replace (Regular Expression) Dreamweaver MX

Tags: dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver MX (yes, I know it is ancient!) and need some help with the Find and Replace (Regular Expression) function.

I am looking to change the line of numbers found this `campid=123456789&` (for example - there are several hundred variables) to this exact code `campid=5339025591&`

I have tried several variations found in answers to similar questions here but nothing seems to work. Any advice will be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I can help with that. In Dreamweaver MX, you can use the Find and Replace function with Regular Expressions to achieve this. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open the **Find and Replace** dialog box. You can do this by going to **Edit > Find and Replace**.
2. In the **Find in** dropdown, select **Source Code** if you want to search the entire source code.
3. In the **Search** dropdown, select **Specific Tag**. In the adjacent field, enter `campid`.
4. In the **Find** field, enter the following regular expression: `campid=\d+&`. This will match any line that starts with `campid=`, followed by one or more digits (`\d+`), and ends with `&`.
5. In the **Replace** field, enter `campid=5339025591&`.
6. Click **Replace All**.

This should replace all instances of `campid=123456789&` (and any other number) with `campid=5339025591&`.

Please remember to backup your files before performing a Find and Replace operation on the source code. Let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work ("not found"), which makes me wonder if there is a problem with my MX programme. The normal search and replace works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Find` field, enter the below regular expression to match the old campid value:

```
campid=\d+&
```

This regular expression will match campid= followed by one or more digits and ending with &.

In the `Replace` field, enter the new desired campid value:

```
campid=5339025591&
```

Check the "Regular expression" option.

do `Find All` once to see we are on the right track and then `Replace All` and done.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work ("not found"), which makes me wonder if there is a problem with my MX programme. The normal search and replace works fine.